# m2e-webby and provided dependencies with jetty

Tags: m2e, embedded-jetty, webby

I have a maven project with some provided dependencies and I am trying to run the application with webby but it give me a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException exception.

In this [link](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Integration+with+Maven+WAR+Plugin) it says: "Webby allows to initialize a launch configuration from the configuration of the jetty-maven-plugin".

My question is it is possible to also pass the dependencies defined in the jetty-maven-plugin? If not how can webby resolve the provided dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want I did was to create a profile in the pom project:

```
<profile>
        <id>webby</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                <version>version</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

And then right click on the project -> properties -> Maven and added webby to the Active Maven Profiles